# Python list: For each columnA value show all the ColumnB values

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a Dataframe and I am trying to combine two columns (one has numeric IDs and the other one strings). So, let's give an example:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to create a list that will show all the columnB values for each value of the columnA (just pasting an excel version and not a list output):

[image]

Initially that was my code:

```
#Group the results by the columns given
scenario = df.groupby(['ColumnA', 'ColumnB', 'ColumnC', 'ColumnD']).agg({'Start_Date': 'min', 'End_Date': 'max', 'Number': 'sum', 'Number2': 'sum'})

 scenario1 = list()
 for row in scenario.itertuples():
    scenario1.append(row[0][0]," ",row[0][1])
```

And that returned this error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

which is a common one.

So, I tried the following scenario too:

```
scenario1.append(row[0][0]," ",row[0][1])
```

with the error:

> append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

and I found a solution (not tested 100%):

```
scenario1.append(str(row[0][0])+" "+row[0][1])
```

When I was trying to find a solution, I converted the dataframe into a json:

```
json_data =json.loads(df.to_json(orient="records"))

    scenario2 = [{"columna": x["ColumnA"], "columnb": x["ColumnB"]} for x in json_data if "columnC" in x and x["ColumnC"] == "one"]
    print(scenario2)
```

which returns an empty list. Please note that I have added a filter for a third column here. I cannot understand why this does not work.

***UPD:***

After jezrael's answer I tried editing it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA':[1111,1111,2222,3333,4444,4444,5555,6666],
                   'columnB':['AAAA','BBBB','AAAA','BBBB','AAAA','CCCC','BBBB','CCCC'],
                   'columnC':['one','one','one','one','one','one','two','one'],
                   'NUM1':[1,3,5,7,1,0,4,5],
                   'NUM2':[5,3,6,9,2,4,1,1],
                   'W':list('aaabbbbb')})

print (df)

d = {'columnB':lambda x: x.tolist(), 'columnC':'first'}
df1 = df.groupby('columnA').agg(d)

print (df1)
```

and I am returning this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need aggregate by `join` all strings columns like `ColumnB` or by `first` if want only first value like `ColumnC`.

If need aggregate `list` use lambda function, like for `ColumnD`:

```
d = {'Start_Date': 'min', 
     'End_Date': 'max', 
     'Number': 'sum', 
     'Number2': 'sum', 
     'ColumnB':', '.join,
     'ColumnC':'first',
     'ColumnD':lambda x: x.tolist()}
scenario = df.groupby(['ColumnA']).agg(d)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':list('abcdef'),
                   'C':list('abcdef'),
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  a  a  1  5  a
1  b  b  b  3  3  a
2  c  c  c  5  6  a
3  d  d  d  7  9  b
4  e  e  e  1  2  b
5  f  f  f  0  4  b

d = {'A':lambda x: x.tolist(), 'B':'first', 'C':','.join, 'D':'min'}
df1 = df.groupby('F').agg(d)
print (df1)
           A  B      C  D
F                        
a  [a, b, c]  a  a,b,c  1
b  [d, e, f]  d  d,e,f  0
```

Comment: I edited my answer using your logic. It seems to be working. Is there a way to filter it directly? I am not sure whether first is reliable here. I want to filter the results only for the "one" values. What if the "two" is the first?

Comment: Something like this: `d = {'columnB':lambda x: x.tolist(), 'columnC':lambda x: x.tolist() if x = "one"}`

Comment: There is possible no `one` value? Do you think change `'columnC':lambda x: x.tolist()  if x = "one"` to `'columnC':lambda x: x[x == 'one'].tolist()` ?

Comment: Yes. My syntax was wrong. But actually, I think I should exclude the rows with the "two" values before doing anything. `df1 = df1[df1['ColumnC'].str.contains('two')]` Or find a way to filter it in the your answer.

Comment: Actually, your version gives me this for the first row: 1111     [AAAA, BBBB]       [one] but it should be 1111     [BBBB]       [one]. It should exclude AAAA if we consider that the first row in the original df is now: 1111    AAAA     two. The second one is 1111    BBBB     one

Comment: I can filter out the df before doing anything. But do you think I can do it here? Neat and tidy.

Comment: Unfortunately now I am offline, so in Monday try to find solution. But you need groupby + apply with custom function and filtering, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48441854/2901002)